# Is it possible to enable content-assist (autocomplete) in Eclipse's Expressions view?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, eclipse-plugin

For example when I debug in **Visual Studio** I have a view with the same functionality where I can create an expressions, and while I'm creating an expression I can use content-assist (autocomplete) exactly like in the main code window.

In Eclipse's **Expression** view, it looks that is absent content-assist functionality or I don't know how to use it. I tried to use **Display** view but it switches between views every time when I need to evaluate an expression, so it isn't convenient.

Is there possible any plugin with required functionality or something?
Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Looks like this bug is still opened in eclipse... https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=57580

Comment: @flafoux, your comment should be an answer.

Comment: @E-riz : Is it considered an answer if the response is no ? :)

Comment: @flafoux, actually I saw this bag report but thought that it can't be true that bug still open from 2006

Comment: @Anatoly : the last bump is from 2014... :)

Comment: @flafoux, in this case I'd say "yes" because the question asks a yes/no question, and you have a reference to the documentation of the known limitation. If you wanted to make the answer really great, you could offer some work-around (if one exists).

Comment: Actually **Display** view in Eclipse is sufficient workaround. You can write an expression like `return root.get(0).getValue();` select it and then choose from right click menu Display option. It will show the result in a same window. It's less convenient then **Expressions** view but can be considered as a temporary replacement.